# AChartEngine : enable scrolling in one direction only

Tags: android, achartengine

I've enabled panning in achartengine with

```
graphRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
```

But I want to disable panning from left-to-right. You would've guessed why! Because otherwise the user is now able to pan beyond the 0 label in X-Axis. can someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setPanLimits`

```
mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { minX, maxX, 0, 1000});
```

For more info see [http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html#setPanLimits(double[])](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html#setPanLimits%28double%5b%5d%29)